# Joining a nested mysql query with field from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table with integers and parameters:

```
date timestamp
123  2013-07-22 16:33:17
123  2013-07-22 16:34:47
234  2013-07-20 16:33:15
332  2013-07-24 16:33:37
422  2013-07-21 10:13:11
422  2013-07-22 14:53:12
```

And I run the following query to get the number of distinct *data* it was choosing from and a random piece of distinct data:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(data)) as count, (SELECT data FROM data_table WHERE
    DATE(timestamp) >= '2013/07/22' AND DATE(timestamp) < '2013/07/23'
    GROUP BY data ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) as data FROM data_table WHERE
    DATE(timestamp) >= '2013/07/22' AND DATE(timestamp) < '2013/07/23'
```

And I get:

```
count  data
2      123
```

or

```
count  data
2      422
```

Now I have another table, *text_table*, whith PRIMARY key *data*. It looks like this:

```
data  text
123   "hi"
234   "hey"
332   "bye"
422   "cya"
```

I need the query to get the result of the previous query, plus the *text*:

```
count  data  text
2      123   "hi"
```

or

```
count  data  text
2      422   "cya"
```

I tried:

```
SELECT text_table.text AS text, COUNT(DISTINCT(data_table.data)) as count,
    (SELECT data FROM data_table GROUP BY data ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) as data
    FROM data_table LEFT OUTER JOIN text_table ON data_table.date = text_table.text
```

But that returns the same *text* all the time, no matter what *data* was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this to get all the info you need.

```
SELECT COUNT(dt.date) count, dt.date, tt.text FROM data_table dt
JOIN text_table tt ON tt.date = dt.date
GROUP BY dt.date, tt.text
```

now you just need to filter it to get the data you want.

like this,

```
SELECT COUNT(dt.date) count, dt.date, tt.text FROM data_table dt
JOIN text_table tt ON tt.date = dt.date
WHERE dt.timestamp > '2013/07/22' AND dt.timestamp < '2013/07/23'
GROUP BY dt.date, tt.text
```

you can also had the top 1 to get just the first line

Thanks,
Chico

Comment: Thank you very much. I had to replace `COUNT(dt.date)` with `(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(data_table.id)) FROM data_table WHERE data_table.time > '2013/07/22' AND data_table.time < '2013/07/23')` to get the total number of records instead of number of records that were **GROUPED BY**. Muito obrigado :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  COUNT(DISTINCT(data_table.data)) as count,
    (SELECT data FROM data_table GROUP BY data ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1) as data 
,text_table.text AS text
FROM data_table JOIN text_table ON data_table.date = text_table.text
```

Comment: It returns me the *text* associated with lowest *data*. In the example above it would return: `2 422 "hi"` instead of `2 422 "cya"`